# Viewpager is not being executed simultaneosuly

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Following is the code that Im using to set up view pagers.
Im setting up it with 4 pagers namely

1. Status
2. Photos
3. Rating
4. Point of contacts.
   Following is the code that im using

   ```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
   ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   adapter.addFrag(new StatusFragment(), "Status");
   adapter.addFrag(new MyOrderPhotos(), "Photos");
   adapter.addFrag(new RatingFragment(), "Rating");
   adapter.addFrag(new Contacts(), "Contact");
   viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);}
   ```

Im using the following code to set up tab icons

```
private void setupTabIcons() {

    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabOne.setText("Status");
    tabOne.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.tab_one_selector, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
    TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabTwo.setText("Photos and Docs");
    tabTwo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.tab_two_selector, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

    TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabThree.setText("Rating");
    tabThree.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.tab_three_selector, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);

    TextView tabFour = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabFour.setText("Point of Contact");
    tabFour.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tabFour.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.tab_four_selector, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFour);
}
```

The problem is that the view pagers are not being executed synchronously.
If the user opens the app, status and photos are being executed.
If the user scrolls to photos, rating is executed and so on and so forth.

Why is that so? How can i be able to sort this out?

Comment: it's viewpager behavior it only execute two page. at the 1st attempt it will execute first two if user moves to 2nd then 3rd and on 3rd it will execute 4th.

Comment: is there any alternative to fix this issue?

Comment: if you want to execute all your pages at the same time then do 1 thing use Nested Viewpager

Comment: how can i be able to change my code to nested view pager?

Comment: inside your first Viewpager Fragment just add another Viewpager and set it.

Comment: i will try than and i will let you know

Comment: it displays nothing